# How to refactor a big function with many if constructs?

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring, dry

We have App A as main app. Now we build from it App B which uses a subset of App A's functionality.

App A stays like it is whereas app B only uses a subset of A

So I want to refactor the function without or with as little dublication as possible and with maximum readability.

So the function looks like this (it is actually longer, this is an excerpt):

```
  class SomeClass {

    Data prepareData() {

     if (this.bothId==1 || this.appAid=2 /*or only relevant for appA*/) {       
        if(this.data==null) { /*appA*/
            appAdoSmth(); /*appA*/
        }
        boolean merge=false; /*appA*/
        if (this.data==null) { /*appA*/
          merge=appAanalyze(data); /*appA*/
        }
        bothPrepare(merge); 
    } else if (bothIsRelevant()) {
      if(appArelevant()) { /*appA*/
        data=appAprepare(); /*appA*/
      } else {
        data=prepareBoth(); 
      }     
      bothUpdateSomeValue();
    }

  }
```

How would you do it?

Comment: Use Eclipse.It has a option to refactor method.It will automatically made new method including its arguments.But you have to think how much code should be refactored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other Answers address the general question of how to refactor code.  They offer good advice, but I don't think it is what you are asking.

I think you are asking about possible refactorings of the code in your question.

It is hard to give an answer that is generally applicable, or even specifically applicable.  (The sample code isn't your real code, and it is a little difficult to understand what it actually "means").

- AndreasD gives one approach: break the big complicated nested `if` into separate methods.
- Another approach is to use the Stragegy design pattern.  Separate the code that is specific to each app into strategy classes.  For example:

  ```
  interface Strategy {
      Data prepareData();
  }

  class GeneralStrategy implements Strategy {
      Data prepareData() {
          // do general preparation
      }
  }

  class App1Strategy extends GeneralStrategy {
      Data prepareData() {
          // do app1-specific preparation
          super.prepareData();
          // do more app1-specific preparation
      }
  }
  ```

and so on.

Comment: I was thinking about using an Abstract Class with a function prepareData(). In prepareData() of that abstract class I replace all Appspecific things with abstract functions and implement them in extended classes. In other words, in one case these functions will be empty because nothing happens there in App B. My mainproblem with the code I have is that there is many times if(){...} if(){...} if(){...}. The first if can or cannot have an influence on the second if, which again, can have an influence on the third. It is ugly code not written by myself. But: not everything is nicely refactorable

Comment: *"But: not everything is nicely refactorable"* - that is correct.  DRY is sometimes an ideal that cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

I ideal world develop unit test that validates that existing implementation of your function works.

Then start changing code incrementally and run your test after every change.
It is hard to give your formal recommendation without knowing your code structure. But generally try to find duplicate code fragments, write methods that implement this logic with parameters and replace the duplicate fragments to your new method. Etc, etc.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would run a coverage report on this class. (e.g. http://ecobertura.johoop.de/ or http://www.eclemma.org/) This way Eclipse can show covered lines green and this helps you to identify the cases. With this aid it's much easier to separate green lines and pull them into methods.

Answer (score 0):

Readbility can be improved by extracting some logic in separate methods. That is a refactoring method.

```
Data prepareData() {
  if (this.bothId==1 || this.appAid=2 ) {
    handleCase1();  // <- you'll find better names for the methods      
  } else if (bothIsRelevant()) {
    handleCase2();
  }
}

private void handleCase1() {
  if(this.data==null) {
    appAdoSmth(); 
  }
  boolean merge=false; 
  if (this.data==null) { 
    merge=appAanalyze(data); 
  }
  bothPrepare(merge); 
}

private handleCase2() {
  if(appArelevant()) { 
    data=appAprepare(); 
  } else {
    data=prepareBoth(); 
  }     
  bothUpdateSomeValue();
}
```

This doesn't reduce the number of if/else, of course, but it keeps the "main" method simple.

Comment: the problem is: this does not simplify the function. E.g. for appB i will have all the calls to things I never use in App B. So I person having to maintain app B will have to look into everything, although I know i never use appAprepare there.